# Moving files and changes from one branch to another branch

Tags: git, repository, git-branch, git-checkout

I am fairly new to git. But currently, I have two branches under master:

`refactor` and `final`. I am trying to move and push all files from `refactor` to `final` however, after checking out to `refactor` and rebasing to `final` I get the final error:

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream final
```

Basically, I am trying to work on my code in `refactor` and after testing to push it to master.

How can I do this?

Comment: How does your *git rebase* command look like? `git rebase final` in *refactor*-branch

Comment: what did you do exactly ?  if you want to merge few files from one branch to another just use `git checkout branchname filename` to your current branch.  if you want to merge all commited from a branch to another use `git merge otherbranch` to your current one.  Or I didn't understand what you were trying to do ... for me no rebase is needed here.

Comment: I have to repositories set in my git. And I like to commit all changes from repository `refactor` to repository `final`. For instance, if I change a file called `index.html` and commit to `refactor` I then want to apply the same changes to `final` @francois-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the end and working backwards—which, incidentally, is what Git does too—let's look at this:

> invalid upstream final

This suggests you ran `git rebase final`, but do not yet have a branch name `final`.

> I am trying to move and push all files from `refactor` to `final`

There's several important things to know here, starting with this: Git isn't really about *files*.  We'll come back to that in a moment, and finish going backwards now:

> But currently, I have two branches under master ...

Branches—more precisely, branch *names*—do not have any kind of over/under relationships.  (This going-backwards stuff is kind of a pain, isn't it?  But it's what Git does, so it's good exercise to do it for a bit. )

Now, the thing to know about Git here is that it's all about *commits*.  It's not about files or branches.  Files and branches are important, of course, but as far as *Git* is concerned, it's the commits that matter.  A commit *holds* files, and we find a commit *using* a branch name.  But Git is all about commits.  What you might like to do, then, is move the commits, but that might also be a problem.  Here's what you need to know.

#### Git is all about commits

Since Git is about commits, you need to know exactly what a commit is and does for you.  So you must memorize a few things:

- Every commit is numbered.  They're not counting numbers, like 1, 2, 3; but each commit has a unique number.  The numbers *look* random, and are big and ugly and have letters in them too: [`385c171a018f2747b329bcfa6be8eda1709e5abd`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/385c171a018f2747b329bcfa6be8eda1709e5abd) for instance.  These numbers are actually cryptographic checksums of everything inside the commit.  Git looks up the commit by this number.
- Each commit has two parts, the *data* and the *metadata:*

  - The data in a commit is simply a snapshot of every file that Git knew about when you (or whoever) made the commit.  These files are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated form.  The de-duplication handles the fact that most commits mostly just re-use all the files from the previous commit.
  - The metadata in a commit contains stuff like your name and email address, and any log message you want to put in.  Git adds its own stuff to this metadata, though: every commit stores the commit-number—the hash ID—of the *previous* commit.  Git calls this the *parent* of the commit.

Most of everything else in Git falls out of these facts:

- Git doesn't store *changes*, but rather snapshots.
- The commits get strung together, in backwards-looking chains:

  ```
   ... <-F <-G <-H
  ```

  Here `H` is the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  If we know the actual hash ID of commit `H`, we can have Git look it up.  That gets both the snapshot, and the actual hash ID of its parent commit `G`.  We can have Git look that up, which gets an earlier snapshot, and the hash ID of even-earlier commit `F`, and so on.
- Because the *number* of a commit is a cryptographic checksum, it's actually not possible to change anything about a commit.  If you take one out and make some changes to it and store the result, you get a *new and different* commit, with a different hash ID.  The old commit is still there, unchanged.
- A branch name just holds the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.
- When you do make a new commit, Git writes the *new* commit's ID into the name:

  ```
   ...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
  ```

  Here, we've added a new commit `I` to `master`.  The existing commits didn't change: `H` still points back to `G`, which still points back to `F`, and so on.  All we did was add a new commit `I` that points back to `H`.  When we did, since we were using `master`, Git wrote `I`'s ID into the *name* `master`.

So the *names* move, but the commits don't change at all.

#### Now we're ready to look at "moving commits"

When you use Git, you generally start with `git checkout branch`.  This copies the files out of one commit—remember, the branch name specifies one commit, and the files inside the commit are in a read-only, Git-only form—to where you can use them.  It also tells Git that that *name* is your current *name*, and therefore that particular *commit* is your current *commit*.  That's what these drawings:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

are all about.  The special name `HEAD` is *attached to* a branch name, like `master`.  That's your current branch, and the commit to which this points is your current commit.

If you now make a new branch name, e.g., `refactor`, you get this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), refactor
```

Once you switch to the name `refactor`, you have this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, refactor (HEAD)
```

Either way, you're still using commit `H`.  It's just that the *name* for commit `H` is either `master` or `refactor`.

Now you make new commits, in the usual way.  If you're on `refactor` when you do that, this is what happens:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- refactor (HEAD)
```

Here, you've made two new commits.  These snapshots, `J` being the *last* one, contain files and metadata.  `J` points back to `I`, which points back to `H`.  The *name* `refactor` selects commit `J` and the name `master` selects commit `H`.

> I [would] like to commit all changes from repository `refactor` to repository `final`

Hang on: you just said *repository*, but earlier, you said *branch*.

A *repository* is a collection of commits (with branch names, which help you and Git *find* the commits).  A *branch* is ... well, it's ambiguous: people use the word to mean different things.  But a *branch name* is a name that helps you and Git find one specific commit, from which Git works backwards as needed.

If you want a new *branch name* spelled `final` that identifies commit `J`, that's easy:

```
git branch final            # makes `final` point to the current commit
```

or:

```
git branch final refactor   # makes `final` point to the same commit as `refactor`
```

The end result might look like this—note that again, no commits have actually *changed:*

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- refactor (HEAD), final
```

#### Git uses words in a very confusing manner

Git has a bunch of technical terms, such as *remote*, *repository*, *branch*, and so on.  Not everyone actually uses these terms the right way (and some of them are just not very good in the first place, and some have evolved over time).  If you're trying to get a question across to a human, or to get Git to do something, it can be very important to use the right terms, or to add a bit of explanation if you're not sure about terminology.

Git has a [glossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary) to help out here.  It's definitely not perfect, but it's a starting point, at least.